# Negate regular expression to exclude complete lines

Tags: java, regex

```
ER430;000000000;
ADR03;000000020;
RID01;000000000;
RID02;000000000;
```

I have above content within a string including new lines. Now i want to cut the string
so only lines with a leading 'R' are left. Result should be:

```
RID01;000000000;
RID02;000000000;
```

Unfortunately i didn't find the solution yet after some hours trying.. thanks for
any help!!

Some of my tests:

```
 content = s.replaceAll("[^R].+;{1}.+;{1}", "");
 content = s.replaceAll("(?!R).*;{1}.*;{1}", "");
 content = s.replaceAll("(?!R)(.+;)(.+;)", "");
```

which all are not exactly bringing the solution..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the multi line flag `(?m)`, which makes `^` and `$` match at newlines, and the DOTALL flag `(?s)`, which makes dot match newlines:

```
str = str.replaceAll("(?sm)^[^R].*?(^|\\Z)", "");
```

The start is straightforward - a non-R char, then
`.*?^` will grab every char up to the *start* of the next line - including the newline char Adding an alternate ending of `\Z` caters for the last line being removed too.

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/rVHqRVdkhT) that includes edge case of last line removal.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the anchors `^`, `$` in your code, you need to include the multiline `(?m)` modifier or DOTALL `(?s)` modifier.

```
String str = "ER430;000000000;\n" + 
        "ADR03;000000020;\n" + 
        "RID01;000000000;\n" + 
        "RID02;000000000;";
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("(?s)(?<=\n|^)[^R][^;\n]*?;[^;\n]*;(\n|$)", ""));
```

Output:

```
RID01;000000000;
RID02;000000000;
```

**OR**

```
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("(?m)(?<=\n|^)[^R][^;\n]*?;[^;\n]*;(\n|$)", ""));
```

Comment: Thanks for that too. It did not match 100% at the first try - cause of the added new lines in your string.. Bohemian's answer did. Thank you both!